# Multiple LIMITS where price1 <> price2

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working with mysql and php.

Lets say I have the following table with more than 400.000 books in my database:

```
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| Item | color | Price1 | Price2 |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
|    1 | blue  |   1.23 |   1.23 |
|    2 | red   |   2.34 |   2.66 |
|    3 | green |   4.55 |   4.55 |
|    4 | blue  |   2.33 |   2.44 |
|    5 | blue  |   3.44 |   3.66 |
|    6 | blue  |   4.55 |   4.66 |
|    7 | ...   |    ... |    ... |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
```

I would like to get the first 5 entries of every color where price1 <> price2. If the affected rows are smaller than 5 ==> Then I would like to get the query filled with entries where price1==price2.

In case of "blue" I would like to get the following result:

```
+------+-------+--------+--------+
| Item | color | Price1 | Price2 |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
|    4 | blue  |   2.33 |   2.44 |
|    5 | blue  |   3.44 |   3.66 |
|    6 | blue  |   4.55 |   4.66 |
|    1 | blue  |   1.23 |   1.23 |
+------+-------+--------+--------+
```

I have a little workaround to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE color = 'blue' AND price1<>price2 ORDER BY price1 LIMIT 5;
```

Get the Affected rows. In this example: 3.
Start another query:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE color = 'blue' price1=price2 ORDER BY price1 LIMIT 2;
//Limit 2, because I ve already 3 rows from the first result.
```

Is there a way to merge this query?

Comment: Let's pretend you have 12 books and 3 colors, and want the first two of each. With that in mind, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Based on your first query results, it seems that you have 4 affected rows not 3, can you please clarify?

Comment: In `ORDER BY price` to which column are you referring? There is no column `price` in your table. Also what is your version of MySql?

Comment: @KurtKline I ve 3 affected rows. The row with item 1 has price1==price". But I am requesting price1<>price2. Thats why only rows 4,5 and 6 affected by th efirst sql query.

Comment: @forpas Order By price1. Sorry. Version of Mysql: 10.4.11-MariaDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the rows of each color so that the rows with `price1 <> price2` appear first.
You can implement this conditional sorting with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT t.Item, t.color, t.Price1, t.Price2  
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY color ORDER BY price1 <> price2 DESC, price1) rn
  FROM books 
) t
WHERE t.rn <= 5
```

If you want results for a specific color:

```
SELECT *
FROM books 
WHERE color = 'blue'
ORDER BY price1 <> price2 DESC, price1
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks so far. I will test it later/early tomorrow.

Comment: 'SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY color ORDER BY price1 <> price2 DESC, price1) rn  FROM books' is not working. I throws #1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY..."

Comment: @Ben For MariaDB 10.4.11 the code runs fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=c7fea7896ea4e4563750bbba3160fbca

Comment: It is working perfect! Thanks. And beside this you solved my other problem to get 5 results of every single solor. I will accept your answer. I ve got another question. I have another table with the wished order the colors should be displayed. table_color_order: [1: red; 2: yellow; 3: blue; 4: green; 5: red]. How can I connect the order of this table with your query with the row_number() statement?

Comment: Something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=1251c74c2466735d516d9242010ad5e5